# Planned Leave: Simple Present vs Future

Tags: sentence-choice, future-constructions

Could anyone please clarify which among the below is correct and why?

> I will be on planned leave today and tomorrow

or

> I am on planned leave today and tomorrow

If I want to communicate this at 8 am before the business starts, which tense should I use? Say I forgot to inform in the morning hours and would like to inform around 11 or 12, then should I use present but not future?

Comment: Both are correct and natural, and common in the workplace, but as most people will read this message while you are on leave, I'd go with present tense. "Will be" suggests you might still be around, especially if it's still the first day. Simple present leaves no doubt that the period of absence has started

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

Both are correct. You can use the simple present for events, actions, or situations that are scheduled or planned, as your leave is. You can also correctly use the future tense.

[Talking about the future (British Council)](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/talking-about-the-future)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but there’s a bit of nuance.  Here’s my advice, for American English.

Leaving aside “today and.” and simply focusing on how you can describe planned or anticpated future actions, you can use the verbs *be on*, *go on* or *start* here, in either the future indicative, future progressive, present indicative, or present progressive. (With the exception that “*I am being on planned leave” is unidiomatic.)  The present tense is less formal, and some teachers might consider it a grammatical error in formal writing.

Ways you could say this include, “I am going on planned leave tomorrow,” “I will start planned leave tomorrow,” “I am on planned leave tomorrow,” and “I will be going on planned leave tomorrow.”

You could also say, “I plan to go on leave tomorrow,” or several variations of it.  This emphasizes the tentativeness: “I am going on leave tommorrow like I planned,” expresses certainty about what will happen.  “I am planning to go on leave tomorrow,” means that is currently the plan, but it might change.  “You are going on leave tomorrow,” is an order, direct enough to be rude.  “You will be on leave tomorrow,” informs someone that they will be put on leave and do not have a choice in the matter.  But it’s possible to soften this: “Right now, you are going on leave tomorrow,” sounds literally like the tenses make no sense.  But, given the previous examples, we can figure it out.  The plan right now, at the moment, is that you will go on leave tomorrow, but it is still provisional and you can get them to change it.

Thinking about it, I’m more likely to use the present indicative for planned events in the short term.  I’d probably say, “I will retire at 67,” or “I am retiring at 67,” and probably would not say, “*I retire at 67.”  On the other hand, “When I retire at 67,” sounds just fine to me.

Comment: Did you read the question?? The whole point is that it is today, not tomorrow.

Comment: "planned leave" is a fixed phrase in a business context, as opposed to unplanned leave such as sick days.The rephrasings that break up this phrase IMO change the intent subtly. Perhaps that is an AmE usage only.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I thought planned leave is leave that’s planned in advance, but thanks for the warning that these are subtly different to you.